# Iframe resizing not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using iframes with added support for drag'n'drop resizing but it's not working very well. MouseUp isn't fired most times. What can I do about it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MB Docs</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:5px;">
        <table id="maingrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;"><tr>
        <div style="float:left;">
            <td><iframe id="ifmenu" name="menu" height="600" width="200" style="border:1px solid #999;"></iframe></td>
            <td id="ifdivider" style="width:3px;cursor:col-resize;"></td>
            <td><iframe id="ifmain" name="main" height="600" width="300"  style="border:1px solid #999;"></iframe></td>
        </tr></table>
    </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doResize() {
            //set height and width of frames
            var h = window.innerHeight - 10;
            $('#ifmenu').css('height', h);
            $('#ifmain').css('height', h);
        }
        
        window.onresize = function(event) {
            doResize();
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            doResize();
            
        //attach drag support divider.
        var isDragging = false;
        var xOffset = 0;
        $('#ifdivider').mousedown(function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
            xOffset = e.pageX;
            console.log('down');
        });

        $('#ifmenu').mouseup(function() {
            isDragging = false;
            console.log('up');            
        });

        $('#maingrid').mousemove(function(e) {            
            if (isDragging && e.pageX < 500) {
                $('#ifmenu').css('width',e.pageX - 2);
                console.log('move');            
            }
        });
        
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do dragging, your mouseUp and mouseMove event could occur on any other element.  It could even not occured at all on some browsers if you mouseUp/mouseMove outside its window boundaries.

You could try to put the mouseUp and mouseMove event on the whole document instead of the specific object, and only when you start dragging, then remove those handlers.

ex. (untested)

```
$('#ifdivider').mousedown(function(e) {

    isDragging = true;
    xOffset = e.pageX;
    console.log('down');

    $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        isDragging = false;
        $(document).off('mousemove.dragging');
        console.log('up');            
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove.dragging', function(e) {       
        if (isDragging && e.pageX < 500) {
            $('#ifmenu').css('width',e.pageX - 2);
            console.log('move');            
        }
    });
});
```